# Remove pagination of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I am using an iframe in my react app to display a pdf, but I want it to all be on one "page" there is a blank "border" separating each page that Id likes to remove entirely.

```
<div className="full-page">
    <iframe title="doc" className="doc" src={file + '#toolbar=0' } frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I have right now

```
.full-page {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
}

.doc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

[image]

One is to change the behavior of every Iframe PDF reader on the Planet, so on the right hand side I can make the gaps bigger or smaller even 0. Thus you need to convince Chromium and Mozilla to do likewise, or provide users with your own binary PDF extender. The Alternative on the Left is to make the Whole PDF one great long roll, since a PDF page can be infinit-ish, that should work practically for a few yards/meters. My longest were 5 mile diagrams at scale but by Jove they were slow to render/scroll.

Comment: Hmm so at this point i think i might just roll with my plan B which is react-pdf and ditch the iframes